# Magento External File(Parallel to index.php): Can't check customer is logged in & total cart items

Tags: magento-1.9, login, cart-items

I have added an external file as same as index.php & having below code.

```
 require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$isLoggedIn = 0;
$isCartItems = 0;

if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $isLoggedIn = 1;
}

$isCartItems = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();

echo $isCartItems;
echo $isLoggedIn;
```

But, unfortunately i can't get correct values of above variables. Its always returning `0`

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<?php 
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $isLoggedIn = 1;
}

$isCartItems = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();

echo $isCartItems;
echo $isLoggedIn;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still same result.

Comment: $isLoggedIn is returning 0 &  $isCartItems returns nothing. I am logged in & having 1 cart item in frontend.

Comment: use `Mage::app('default');` because i am using this code and working for me

Comment: Tried this also but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i read in the session data by hand. Try the following:

```
<?php
require_once("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/shop/app/Mage.php");

$cookie_exists = isset($_COOKIE['frontend']);

if($cookie_exists){
    $file = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/shop/var/session/sess_{$_COOKIE['frontend']}";
    if(file_exists($file)){
        $data = file_get_contents("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/shop/var/session/sess_{$_COOKIE['frontend']}");
        session_decode($data);
    }
}

Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array("name" => "frontend"));

if($cookie_exists) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('value' => $_COOKIE['frontend']));
    }
}

$isLoogedIn = 0;

if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $isLoggedIn = 1;
}

$isCartItems = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();

echo $isCartItems;
echo $isLoggedIn;
```