# How can we get "is CustomerLoggedin" & "Cart having some items" using core PHP not Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

Is there any way to get "`is CustomerLoggedin`" & "`Cart having some items`" In core PHP file that i have created parallel to `index.php` file.

I think **using some cookies** we can get those values. But not sure how.

Anyone can help here

Comment: the cart items come from the db so you will have to touch Magento somehow in order to get it.

Comment: why did you want core php? you can also use magento syntax in file you create paralle to index.php

Comment: Marius can you confirm if only using core PHP  session or cookies  we can find this. Else will look some other way.

Comment: @Kul i tried magento way also as second thought. It should work but don't know why that is also not working. Can you pls see here -http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147062/magento-external-fileparallel-to-index-php-cant-check-customer-is-logged-in  No solution in that question is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    ...loged in
}
```

Comment: Thanks..! But any core PHP way to find this. As i asked in question.

Comment: @PHP, Yes, You have to make a php file on the root folder of your magento project and use this code only. It will work. Just make sure this file will be on the magento root directory

Comment: No, Actually instead using Magento session any PHP session or cookies can be used?

Comment: @PHP I don't think its possible. User data and quote data always will be in session. And you want to use magento user data, so you have to use magento session.